# Set the default value for dropdown menu

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i set the default value for the drop down menu to ghana amongst a list of countries

```
          const Center(child: CountryDropdown()),

          Padding(
            padding: AppDimensions.padding.defaultHorizontal(),
            child: CountriesListDropdown(
              onUpdateNationality: (CountryModel? country) {
                kentry = country?.name ?? "Ghana";
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: _size.height * (30 / 812)),
          Center(
```

Comment: which package are you using?

Comment: Are you using any plugin ? or if using custom dropdown used the value variable and it will set the default value and you can update it onChange().

Answer (score 1):

Give value parameter to dropdown widget like this:

```
DropdownButton(
  underline: Container(),
  dropdownColor: themeData.cardColor,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
 //give default value here
  value: "give you default value here",
 
  items: [],
  onChanged: (){}
)
```